# Run Keycloak 20 behind reverse proxy. Why is there still Strict HTTPS: true and Proxied: false?

Tags: keycloak, reverse-proxy

I find a very strange error while trying to run Keycloak on a Docker. Even if I set the proxy to edge and so on, in logs I can see they are not setted as I did:

```
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:20.0.0 as builder

# go root to do copy and rights stuff
USER root

# Fix timezone issue
ENV TZ=Europe/Vienna
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

ENV KC_HEALTH_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_METRICS_ENABLED=true
ENV KC_FEATURES=token-exchange
ENV KG_HTTPS=true
ENV KC_PROXY=edge
ENV KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT=false
ENV KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS=false
# Install custom providers
RUN curl -sL https://github.com/aerogear/keycloak-metrics-spi/releases/download/3.0.0/keycloak-metrics-spi-3.0.0.jar -o /opt/keycloak/providers/keycloak-metrics-spi-3.0.0.jar
RUN /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh build

FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
COPY --from=builder /opt/keycloak/ /opt/keycloak/
WORKDIR /opt/keycloak
COPY themes/mydomain /opt/keycloak/themes/mydomain

# change these values to point to a running postgres instance
ENV KC_DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://hostname:port/keycloak
ENV KC_DB_USERNAME=user
ENV KC_DB_PASSWORD=password
ENV KC_HOSTNAME=http://keycloak-test.mydomain.com
ENV KC_DB=postgres
ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh","start","--log-level=info"]
~
```

And in the logs:
(main) Hostname settings: Base URL: , Hostname: http://keycloak-test.mydomain.com, **Strict HTTPS: true**, Path: , Strict BackChannel: false, Admin URL: , Admin: , Port: -1, **Proxied: false**

What is overriding my setting?